# I keep getting this error (Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-navigation/native'). even though I have 'react-navigation/native' installed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v6

this is my file i have made sure to install both @react-navigation/stack and @react-navigation/native. and I still get this issue. also I am using expo

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createAppContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';                                     
import HomeScreen from '../pages/home';
import DiscoverScreen from '../pages/discover';

const screens = {
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Discover: { screen:DiscoverScreen }
}

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(screens);
export default createAppContainer(HomeStack);
```

and for some reason I keep getting this error in the terminal I have tried to re install the react navigation native package however I still get this error. not sure why

```
"export 'createAppContainer' was not found in '@react-navigation/native'
15 | const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(screens);

16 | const Appjs =createAppContainer(HomeStack);
                                                                                             
17 | export default Appjs;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check what version of react-navigation you are using, createAppContainer was removed in favor of NavigationContainer in recent versions

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>{/* ... */}</Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```